# Bind iterations of a loop as rows in a data.frame for each i

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, dplyr

I have this `dplyr` pipe in a loop that works fine (the `print()` is just so that I can see what i'm doing while working on it):

```
for (species in species_vector) {
  for (month in month_vector) {
    print(
      data_fish %>%
        filter(Species == species,
               Month == month,
               Lt %in% some_vector%>%
        group_by(Month) %>%
        summarise(Mean_Lt = mean(Lt),
                  StDev_Lt = sd(Lt),
                  Count = sum(Count))%>%
        as.data.frame()%>%
        
    )
  }
}
```

Each iteration produces a different `data.frame` for each month of each species. This is one example of the results of one month (3 OR March) for one species:

```
Month  Mean_Lt  StDev_Lt Count
3      4.3303   0.7742   221
```

**My problem is**: I would like to `rbind()` all the months belonging to each species in separate dfs. Ending up with a df for each species, each df containing all months regarding that species.

Comment: look at `purrr::map_dfr`, this is what you need [link](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general approach using lists:

```r
output_list = list()

for(species in species_vector){
  species_df = data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  for(month in month_vector){
    # build result_for_month
    # ...
    species_df = rbind(species_df, result_for_month)
  }
  output_list[species] <- species_df
}
```

You can then access your outputs using:

```r
output_list[["my_species"]]
```